# How to configure HTTPS (TLS/SSL) using self signed certificate in Docker Container in Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker, ssl, .net-core, https, docker-desktop

I am not able to configure SSL self signed certificate in container.

I tried every possible scenarios, but no luck

```
....
 Hosting failed to start
      System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
      To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
      For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
....
```

Following are the commands used to create self signed certificate

I am using ***Windows using Linux containers***

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep $env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https\WeatherApi.pfx -p password

dotnet dev-certs https --trust

dotnet user-secrets -p WeatherApi.csproj set "Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password" "password"

docker run --rm -it -p 8001:8001 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=8001 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -v $env:APPDATA\microsoft\UserSecrets\:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets -v $env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https:/root/.aspnet/https/ weatherapi
```

[image]

[image]

Reference document: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/run-aspnetcore-https-development.md

I am hosting docker images/container locally in Docker Desktop.

Please note that I am not using docker compose.

**Dockerfile code**

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AV.Identity.A/AV.Identity.A.csproj", "AV.Identity.A/"]
COPY ["AV.Identity.B/AV.Identity.B.csproj", "AV.Identity.B/"]
COPY ["AV.Identity.D/AV.Identity.D.csproj", "AV.Identity.D/"]
COPY ["AV.Identity.C/AV.Identity.C.csproj", "AV.Identity.C/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./AV.Identity.A/./AV.Identity.A.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/AV.Identity.A"
RUN dotnet build "./AV.Identity.A.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./AV.Identity.A.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AV.Identity.A.dll"]
```

Comment: There's nothing Docker-specific here, other than maybe telling it to publish port 443 instead of port 80.  Whatever work you'd need to do to get a valid TLS certificate and configure your application to use it is essentially the same.

Comment: No luck David. I tried many approaches.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the way the user secrets are passed. If you pass the password to `docker run` via the commandline, it should work.